# how to make icon for your website in topbar

Tags: html, css, image

hello i want to know how to make icon lik this in topbar
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ga7Zs.jpg)

Comment: Look up the term "favicon".  Also look at the *actual HTML* of the sites you're referencing (like this one).  Do you see anything helpful at the very beginning of the `<head>` element?

Comment: thanks man i'll try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can you use a generator like this one to turn any image into a favicon
https://wwww.favicon-generator.org/
Then you include in the head of your html from whatever folder it's in, before the title `<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.ico" />`

Answer (score 3):

That is an element called `favicon`. You can generate it with the next tools

http://www.consultsarath.com/public-utilities/high-quality-online-favicon-generator.aspx
http://www.xiconeditor.com/

You can added in your `<head>` using the next line of code:

```
<link href="favicon.ico" rel="favicon" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Hope this helps :>

Comment: ur welcome, pliss dont forget to upvote if it helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

The icon you talk about is called "favicon".
The favicon is an .ico picture.

This icon must be square.
The best way to use it is to place it a the root of your web directory (or in an other folder). You have to link the favicon in your html   like :

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
```

Thanks.